# Basic Join Query Not Yielding All Columns when using "Select *"

Tags: sql, join, select, db-browser-sqlite

I'm taking a SQL Essentials training course. It's time to learn Joins and the instructor is having us use DB Browser. So far, everything has worked great; until this lesson.

The instructor has us make a query that will join a customer and invoice table and then give all columns using 'SELECT *'. My query works, but all it's giving me are the results from one table, not both.

In the video, the instructor is doing exactly the same thing I'm attempting and he's getting results. I'm wondering if this is as simple as a setting in the application itself.

I've tried specifically selecting columns from both tables and that works as expected, but when I try to select all, it still only gives the results to one table. The query is dead simple.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Invoice
INNER JOIN
    Customer
ON
    Invoice.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
ORDER BY
    Customer.CustomerId
```

Comment: This should return results from both tables, unless there are duplicate column names. Those will only come from one table.

Comment: That's precisely what I'm expecting as well, and yet, in this case it's only returning results from the Invoice table and nothing from Customer.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with DB Browser, try using another query interface.

Comment: The problem was me. I'm even embarrassed how dumb it was that I didn't just use the scroll bar to scroll and assumed my mouse scroll worked correctly in the application (it does not).

Comment: Workbench on a laptop?  My scroll never works for Workbench installed on Windows --  Especially touch pad.

Comment: I've learned a humbling and valuable lesson today.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic PICNIC error.

The results were displayed, but when I scrolled left and right, it skipped past the columns I thought were missing.

Apologies for the fire drill, please feel free to close this question.

Comment: What's a PICNIC error? Is it like PEBKAC?

Comment: Yup, "Problem In Chair, Not In Computer".

Comment: I like that better :)

Comment: Closing questions in StackOverflow only means that no new answers can be added.

You should try deleting your question instead. Press "Delete" under the question.